# ECC decryption corresponding to ECIES from Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, ruby, encryption, cryptography, openssl

I am trying to decrypt files in Ruby which were encrypted with ECIES in Java using

- BouncyCastle as JCE Provider
- ECIES Algorithm
- P-384 named curve

In Java the encryption was done using Cipher.doFinal() and then written to a file. A test case implements encryption and decryption.

In Ruby all i can find is the OpenSSL::PKey::EC implementation, but this does not seem to have encryption or decryption but only Verify and Sign.

Does anyone know of a way to do this in Ruby? My worst case scenario would be to simply call the Java decryption routing from Ruby, but that really isn't the way i want to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ECC decryption corresponding to ECIES from Bouncy Castle

ECIES is Shoup's Integrated Encryption System. Its much more than simply EC encrypt and decrypt. You can find Shoup's paper at [A Proposal for an ISO Standard for Public Key Encryption](http://www.shoup.net/papers/iso-2_1.pdf).

---

> In Ruby all i can find is the OpenSSL::PKey::EC implementation

OpenSSL does *not* have an ECIES implementation. It does not have an implementation of Abdalla, Bellare, and Rogaway's DHAES, either.

---

> My worst case scenario would be to simply call the Java decryption routing from Ruby, but that really isn't the way i want to go.

You will probably have to shell out to Java.

---

Related (sorry about wandering into C++): [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) also has ECIES. However, the Bouncy Castle and Crypto++ implementations *do not* inter-operate out of the box. See [Problem with the way gfpcrypt HMAC's the encoding parameters' length in DHAES_MODE](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/vR8GSL8wxPA/Bf9koUDyZ88J) on the Crypto++ mailing list.

The interop issue is a difference in the size of a label that gets hashed as a security parameter when using `DHAES_MODE`. Crypto++ uses a 8-octet label, while Bouncy Castle uses a 4-octet label. I don't recall who was/is correct.

At the bottom of the Crypto++ page on [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme), there's a patch available based on Jessie Wilson's comments at `cryptopp-ecies-bc.zip`. Download it, apply it, and use the `ECIES_BC` class rather than the `ECIES` class.

Here's the essence of the patch. `BC_COMPAT` is a template parameter.

```
diff --git a/gfpcrypt.h b/gfpcrypt.h
index 7af993f..18ea104 100644
--- a/gfpcrypt.h
+++ b/gfpcrypt.h
@@ -408,7 +408,9 @@ CRYPTOPP_DLL_TEMPLATE_CLASS DL_PrivateKey_GFP<DL_GroupParameters_DSA>;
 CRYPTOPP_DLL_TEMPLATE_CLASS DL_PrivateKey_WithSignaturePairwiseConsistencyTest<DL_PrivateKey_GFP<DL_GroupParameters_DSA>, DSA2<SHA> >;

 //! the XOR encryption method, for use with DL-based cryptosystems
-template <class MAC, bool DHAES_MODE>
+// Set BC_COMPAT=true if interop'ing with Bouncy Castle. Thanks to Jesse Wilson and Daniele Perito.
+//   See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/vR8GSL8wxPA/Bf9koUDyZ88J.
+template <class MAC, bool DHAES_MODE, bool BC_COMPAT = false>
 class DL_EncryptionAlgorithm_Xor : public DL_SymmetricEncryptionAlgorithm
 {
 public:
@@ -442,9 +444,17 @@ public:
        mac.Update(encodingParameters.begin(), encodingParameters.size());
        if (DHAES_MODE)
        {
-           byte L[8] = {0,0,0,0};
-           PutWord(false, BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER, L+4, word32(encodingParameters.size()));
-           mac.Update(L, 8);
+           if (BC_COMPAT) {
+               byte L[4];
+               PutWord(false, BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER, L, word32(8 * encodingParameters.size()));
+               mac.Update(L, 4);
+           }
+           else
+           {
+               byte L[8] = {0,0,0,0};
+               PutWord(false, BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER, L+4, word32(encodingParameters.size()));
+               mac.Update(L, 8);
+           }
        }
        mac.Final(ciphertext + plaintextLength);
    }
@@ -471,9 +481,17 @@ public:
        mac.Update(encodingParameters.begin(), encodingParameters.size());
        if (DHAES_MODE)
        {
-           byte L[8] = {0,0,0,0};
-           PutWord(false, BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER, L+4, word32(encodingParameters.size()));
-           mac.Update(L, 8);
+           if (BC_COMPAT) {
+               byte L[4];
+               PutWord(false, BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER, L, word32(8 * encodingParameters.size()));
+               mac.Update(L, 4);
+           }
+           else
+           {
+               byte L[8] = {0,0,0,0};
+               PutWord(false, BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER, L+4, word32(encodingParameters.size()));
+               mac.Update(L, 8);
+           }
        }
        if (!mac.Verify(ciphertext + plaintextLength))
            return DecodingResult();
```